# почему не выводится последнее слово "программы"

Tags: java

почему не выводится последнее слово "программы"

Ввожу текст "Это просто текст, для примера работы программы"

Результат

(1) Это (2) просто (3) текст, (4) для (5) примера (6) работы

```
package practice.string;

public class SequentialWordsNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите текст:");
        String text = "Это просто текст, для примера работы программы";
        System.out.println(text);
        System.out.println("Результат");
        System.out.println(sequentialWordsNumbers(text));
    }

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    public static String sequentialWordsNumbers(String text) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        String word = "";

        for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {

            if (text.charAt(index) != ' ') {
                word = word + text.charAt(index);
            } else {
                i++;
                stringBuilder.append(" (" + i + ") " + word);
                word = "";
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Введите текст:
Это просто текст, для примера работы программы
Результат
 (1) Это (2) просто (3) текст, (4) для (5) примера (6) работы

Comment: Вы помещаете слово в результат когда находите пробел после него (слова). После последнего слова нет пробела, оно никогда не попадает в результат. Используйте отладчик чтобы проверять как работа вашей программы соответствует вашим желаниям.

Comment: а что такое отладчик?

Comment: Отладчик есть в Intellij Idea: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/753-rukovodstvo-poljhzovatelja-intellij-idea-otladchik.

Answer (score 0):

"Это просто текст, для примера работы программы "
Если поставить пробел в конце текста то будет работать ).

---

Вот пример где будет работать и без пробела в конце:

```
public static String sequentialWordsNumbers(String text) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 1;
        //Разбиваем строку на массив строк через каждый пробел
        String[] word = text.split(" ");

        //Проходим по каждому элементу массива и добавляем в stringBuilder вместе с нумерацией
        for(String w : word){
            stringBuilder.append("(" + i + ") " + w + " ");
            i++;
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: я еще не проходила массивы, без них можно как то и без регулярных выражений